# AT Commands For T-Mobile G1

Tags: android

I want to fetch DTMF in my application using AT Commands.
I have a T Mobile G1 android 2.2.
so How can I Use AT Commands in my application and from where can i get list of AT Commands for T Mobile G1?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `invokeOemRilRequestRaw()` and `invokeOemRilRequestStrings()` methods which have implementations in a number of classes: `RIL`, `PhoneProxy`, `PhoneBase`, and some others.

However, these are not available through the SDK. Even sidestepping the SDK, I haven't found a way to get access to them.